# Second level cache of Hibernate is not updated automatically with ManyToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, second-level-cache

I create 2 classes as User & Profle which have @ManyToMany relationship as below:

Class Profile

```
@Cache (usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"name"}))
public class Profile implements Serializable {

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinTable(name = "User_Profile", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "profiles_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") })
    public Set<User> getUsers() {
       return m_users;
    }
}
```

and class User

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Cache (usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "User_Profile", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "profiles_id") })
public Set<Profile> getProfiles() {
    return m_profiles;
}

}
```

Now, I update list user of profile as below

```
public void saveProfile(Profile profile, List<User> users){ 

    profile.getUsers().clear();
// Make bulk users to profile

profile.getUsers().addAll(users);

    getSession().saveOrUpdate(profile);
}
```

and then I call the getUser(userName) as below

```
public User getUser(String userName) {
   User user = createCriteria().add(Restrictions.eq("name", userName)).uniqueResult());

   // ISSUE HERE
   List<Profile> profile = user.getProfiles(); 
   // The cache still keep the old value of profiles in users. 
}
```

The problem is when I get profiles of user, it still keep the old profiles of user. However, when I call evict to refresh the cache, it is working fine.

Is there anybody facing the same problem with me? Does hibernate support to refresh the cache automatically when new record is added or removed?

Please help!

Comment: What is the fetch type of your collection(Lazy or Eager)?.As you said when you are evicting it's working fine that is because it is taking from first level cache while you are evicting.

Comment: @I have this error as well. It is driving me crazy. I have literally tried everything. Evict might work but I shouldn't have too. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585532/hibernate-criteria-query-returning-outdated-manytomany-relationship